# Dividir slides em ppts Diferrentes

Tags: c#, office-2013

Estou utilizando o projeto "Powerpoint Add in 1" no Visual Studio 2013, e tenho o seguinte problema, tenho um .ppt  com 2 slides, preciso separar esses 2 slides em apresentações diferentes para que eu possa fazer 2 videos diferentes, 1º vídeo referente ao slide 1 e o 2º vídeo referente ao slide 2, porem eu só estou conseguindo fazer um vídeo único com os 2 slides.

```
        string fileName = @"C:\testewiplay.pptx";
        string exportName = "video_of_presentation";
        string exportPath = @"C:\{0}.mp4";


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        ppApp.WindowState = PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(fileName,
                    MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                     MsoTriState.msoTrue);

        try
        {

            oPres.Convert2(fileName);
            oPres.CreateVideo(exportName, true, 5, 1080, 25,     100);

            oPres.SaveCopyAs(String.Format(exportPath, exportName),
                PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsMP4,
                MsoTriState.msoCTrue);

        }
        catch (Exception msg)
        {

           var mensagem = msg.Message;

        }
        finally
        {

            ppApp.Quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

essa foi a solução que eu consegui pesquisar!

```
string fileName = @"C:\wiplay\pp\testewiplay.pptx";
            string exportName = "video_of_presentation";
            string exportPath = @"C:\wiplay\pp\{0}.mp4";


            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            ppApp.WindowState = PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(fileName,
            //            MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue,
            //             MsoTriState.msoTrue);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(fileName,
                      MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                       MsoTriState.msoTrue);
            try
            {
            List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation> lista = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= oPresSet.Count; i++)
            {
                lista.Add(oPres);
            }
            int a = 0;
            int slide_count = oPres.Slides.Count;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide in oPres.Slides)
            {

                slide.Delete();
                oPres.CreateVideo(exportName, true, 5, 1080, 25, 100);
                oPres.SaveCopyAs(String.Format(exportPath, exportName + a),
                    PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsMP4,
                    MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
                a++;
            }
        }
        finally
        {

            ppApp.Quit();
        }
```